# difference between RemoveFromRunningloop and Unschedule

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I have been doing some iOS development using Xamarin. I am pretty new to this so excuse my bad terminology.

I have an `EASession` output and input stream I schedule and delegate as follow:

```
SESSION.InputStream.Delegate = new InputStreamDelegate(Input); ;
SESSION.InputStream.Schedule(NSRunLoop.Current,NSRunLoop.NSDefaultRunLoopMode);
SESSION.InputStream.Open();
```

According to the Apple developer documentation I should then do the reverse when I finish. This is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002274-BAJCABBC). Namely:
1) close 
2) remove from run loop (using removeFromRunLoop)
3) release

Now, I tried to use `removeFromRunLoop` which is "described" on the [Xamarin API Documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.CoreAnimation.CADisplayLink.RemoveFromRunLoop%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSRunLoop,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString%29) which gave me the error :

> 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSStream' does not contain a definition for
>   'removeFromRunLoop' and no extension method 'removeFromRunLoop'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSStream'
>   could be found

I did found the [`Unschedule`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSNetService.Unschedule%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSRunLoop,System.String%29) method which works well.

Can any one tell me what is the difference between them and also any clues as to why the  removeFromRunLoop method didn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "RemoveFromRunLoop" method that you linked to is for CADisplayLink which is not related to the InputStream.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. Does that mean that Unschedule is in fact the equivalent of RemoveFromRunLoop on iOS? I am pretty sure that Xamarin covered 100% of the native API's.